# How come my switch is triggering with out pushing the button?

Tags: arduino-uno

New here, sorry If my formatting is bad.

```
int button = 2;
int relay = 3;
int speaker = 4;

void setup() 
{

  pinMode(button, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(relay, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(speaker, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() 
{
  if(digitalRead(button) == 0)
  {
    digitalWrite(relay, HIGH);
    tone (speaker, 100, 300);
    delay (3000);
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(relay, LOW);
  }
}
```

I want the relay to trigger and stay open only while the button is pressed.   However for some reason touching pin 2 triggers the relay and sound, even if I'm not connecting it to the ground.

If i remove the `tone (speaker, 100, 300);` it only triggers when the button connecting pin 2 to ground is pressed, but obviously doesn't play the tone.

Comment: how is the speaker wired?

Comment: @Gerben, sorry, I had it right on the board but copied it wrong to here.

Comment: @Juraj, The red wire is in pin 4 and the black is in GND on POWER

Comment: is it a piezo speaker? because normal speaker should not be connected without resistor?

Comment: @juraj The piezo is a speaker, however that can't be the issue entirely as even if I don't plug in the speaker, just the code causes the error.

Comment: I can't see any red or black wires in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want the relay to trigger and stay open only while the button is
>   pressed. However for some reason touching pin 2 triggers the relay and
>   sound, even if I'm not connecting it to the ground.

Touching a pin is like connecting it to ground with a resistor (human body is conductive). It may or may not be stronger then the pull-up resistor.

> If i remove the tone (speaker, 100, 300); it only triggers when the
>   button connecting pin 2 to ground is pressed, but obviously doesn't
>   play the tone.

Activation of the neighbor pin influences the pull-up on pin 2. Try external pull-up on pin 2.